# Design: Does it make sense to separate the "application server" from the "web server"?

Tags: angularjs, web

I'd like to build an "application" that'll be consumed by:

1. Users who go to a website with their browsers to use it.
2. Integrators who use HTTPS/REST API to interface with it.
3. Users who run it on their mobile device with a native app.

Putting load balancing or database issues aside for a moment, my initial thought was to architect it with these high level back-end components:

1. "Application Server" to support both external API for 3rd API integrators (#2 on the top list) and internal API to be consumed by Mobile applications (#3 on the top list) and a single page web application. Let's call this server "app.myapplication.net"
2. "Website Server" - to support the my company's public website and serve the AngularJS web application pages that make use of the internal API's in "Application Server" to fetch data back an forth. Let's call it "www.myapplication.com"

My motivation is complete separation of front end from back end work.

Is this a popular way to architect this? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed the most common method. However, for smaller projects, you likely can start off having them colocated and split later. 
There are several advantages of splitting the static content from the application resources. On projects that I have worked on, the pros are resources, release management and to a lesser degree, browser limitations.

1. **Cookies are expensive**; If you colocate the static and application content, every little request will have be burdened with carrying cookies. Cookies also means that the browser will consider that all requests to the server might have different responses for different users, so that may defeat caching of resources. If you serve the static from a domain without cookies, you can ensure that caching works properly.
2. **Resource usage**. You are likely already serving static content from other services, angularjs, that you referred to, you likely refer to by another domain name. Older browsers likes this since they limit the number of concurrent requests to a single web server to 2. It is therefore common to split resources across multiple domains, "domain sharding". This allows the browser to work in parallel.
3. **Release Management**. Now this depends on the team(s) that will be working on the application, but we typically want the application and front end javascripts to be separated, so that front end programmers and designers can release the static content separately without having to trigger a release of the applications.
4. **Performance**. Depending on the application and server, you may also find that you can achieve higher performance if it does not have to scan for .htaccess and similar.
5. **Content Delivery Networks** provides you with primarily a distribution of static content, so that your customers can reach heavy files in a location closer, with lower latency. You can certainly move to a CDN later on and is probably not needed from day one, but if you have started out with your application being on two separate domains, you might find this exercise being easier when/if you decide to do this.